# Using ReactNative External library in ClojureScript Project - Syntax

Tags: react-native, clojurescript, reagent, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I am trying to use [react-native-swipe-list-view](https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view) inside clojurescript. But I am having some trouble in converting documented js code in cljs code.

**Documentations:**

```
import { SwipeRow } from 'react-native-swipe-list-view';
<SwipeRow>
     <View>
     </View>
</SwipeRow>
```

**My Cljs Code:**

```
(:require [react-native-swipe-list-view :as swipe_list])

(defn item[]
(
    [swipe_list/SwipeRow
    [:View]]
))
```

**Online [tool](https://roman01la.github.io/javascript-to-clojurescript/):**

```
(def SwipeRow (.-SwipeRow (js/require "react-native-swipe-list-view")))
(defn item[]
(
    [SwipeRow
    [:View]]
))
```

None of the above worked. I am new to cljs. it will be a big help if someone can tell me how to convert the above lines of js into cljs. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reagent Documents**: [Creating Reagent "Components" from React Components](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/InteropWithReact.md#creating-reagent-components-from-react-components)

Here I am going to create two reagent components, view and swipeRow. I am using different ways for both, to show two ways for importing library and creating components. You can use either.

```
;; Importing Reagent and React Native
(ns type_name_server_here
  (:require [reagent.core :as reagent]
            ["react-native" :as rn]))


;; 1st Way: Importing SwipeRow
(def SwipeRowImport (.-SwipeRow (js/require "react-native-swipe-list-view")))
;; Converting it into Reagent Component
(def SwipeRow (reagent/adapt-react-class SwipeRowImport))

;; 2nd Way: Importing View from already imported react-native library and converting it into reagent component
(def view (reagent/adapt-react-class (.-View ^js rn)))

;; SwipeRow requires two children (Check out documentation)
(defn item[]
(
    [SwipeRow
    [view] [view]]
))
```

If you are using shadow-cljs, you can use this [table](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#_using_npm_packages) as a reference, for converting ES6 Import statments to CLJS Require